# Setting an Individual Hangfire Job to Have Longer Auto Retry timeout Value

Tags: hangfire

I know Hangfire has a logic of auto re-queue jobs that have been running for >30 minutes.

But I have a job that will run for >30 minutes and I don't want any auto-retry.

Meanwhile, I have some jobs that need auto-retry.

Is there anything to configure an individual job's auto-retry-timeout value?

e.g. I manually configure job A's value to 24 hours so it can run for 24 hours without any timeout retry while other jobs remain the same and are auto re-queued when their execution time exceeded 30 minutes.